# Storing incoming email - access denied error when emails arrive simultaneously

Tags: event-receivers, email

I have created a SPEmailEventReceiver to parse and to process incoming emails. before I try to parse a email I store this email as eml-file in a document library. Everything works fine until two or more emails arrive simultaneously. After the first email I get a "access denied"-error, if I try to add a file to the library.

This is the code:

```
private void StoreEmail(SPList list, SPEmailMessage emailMessage, string receiverData)
    {

            LogMessage("StoreEmail called");

            SPFolder folder = list.RootFolder;
            String folderUrl = folder.Url;
            string name = WorkflowHelper.CleanInvalidSPCharacters(emailMessage.Headers["Subject"]);
            String url = String.Format(@"{0}/{1}.eml", folderUrl, name);
            LogMessage("url: " + url);

            byte[] binaryContent = null;
            String mailContent = String.Empty;
            using (Stream stream = emailMessage.GetMessageStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    mailContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    sr.Close();
                }
                binaryContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mailContent);
                stream.Close();
            }

            SPFile file = folder.Files.Add(url, binaryContent, true);
            list.Update();

    }
```

The error happens at "SPFile file = folder.Files.Add(url, binaryContent, true);"

I try to add a lock around the code but it does not help. Any ideas?

Best regards,
AHO